# How to add difficulty levels to a Guess The Number game using rand()?

Tags: c++, game-mechanics, game-loop

User guesses a random number (between 1 and 100 or 5000 and 25,000 depending on difficulty) that the computer picks.

User selects difficulty from list, difficulty (1, 2, 3, 4) is assigned to `int level`. Using `do while` loops to check for difficulty.

Here is the current `do while` loop for level 1:

```
do 
{

srand(time(0)); // seed the random number generator

int theNumber = rand() % 100 + 1; // random number between 1 and 100
int tries = 0, guess;


    do
    {

        cout << "Enter a guess: ";

        string str;
        cin >> str;
        istringstream iss(str);
        iss >> guess ;
        if (iss.eof() == false)
            cout << "\n\nPlease enter only numbers.\n\n";
        else
        {

            ++tries;

            if (guess > theNumber)
            cout << "Too high!\n\n";

            if (guess < theNumber)
            cout << "Too low!\n\n";
        }

    } while (guess != theNumber);

cout << "\nThat's it! You got it in " << tries << " guesses!\n";

cout << "Play again? (y/n)\n";
cin >> playAgain;

} while (playAgain == 'y' && level == 1);
```

What I need help with is the `int theNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;` section. What do I need to change to allow the random number to be between 100 and 1000, 1000 and 5000, 5000 and 25000?

It would also be extremely valuable information to me if you could explain how `rand() % x + y;` works.

**EDIT**

I know that `rand() = 32767` (for me). I'm just not sure as to how `rand() % x + y` works. I'm actually not sure what the `modulo (%)` operator does. If someone could explain that with an example, it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You might want to take a look at other random number generators. It can be a great thing to learn, not just to improve your generation but also to learn how to implement libraries in your C++ projects.

Comment: Fundamentally this is the same as this question on SO, and not game-specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range

Answer (score 2):

`rand() % 900 + 100` would be between 100 and (900+100)
`rand() % 20000 + 5000` would be between 5000 and (20000+5000), etc.

`rand()` gives you a random number from 0 up to a built-in limit (generally 32,767).

`rand() % 10` gives you a number from 0 to 9.  What happens is `%` takes that big number and divides it by 10 and gives you what remains.

`rand() % 10 + 1` gets rid of that 0 and gives you a number from 1 to the number after your `%` (10, in this case).

That's about it, good luck !